# Perl adding CR at end of substr()

Tags: perl, substr

I am doing this line to limit the size of text lines. 
`$Line=substr($_,0,12)`. But if truncation happened the returned strings lack the CR at the end. Without truncation all is OK. Thus when I print my lines the truncated ones don't have a CR and the line continues and gets garbled. Is there anything built-in to do this automatically or will it require extra if-clause to fix this?
Thanks Gert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mean Line Feed (`0A`) rather than Carriage Return (`0D`).

The solution is to remove the existing line feed before truncating the line, and re-adding it afterwards.

```
chomp;
$_ = substr($_, 0, 12);
say;
```

You could also use concatenation (`$_ .= "\n";`), of course.

Comment: If this is in the context of a one-liner using `-n` or `-p`, the `-l` option is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

One way

```
$line =~ s/(.{12}).*/$1/;
```

or, better

```
$line =~ s/.{12}\K.*//;
```

where `\K` drops all previous matches; see "*Lookaround Assertions*" [in Extended Patterns in perlre](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Extended-Patterns).  The newline remains since `.` doesn't match it.  This assumes that the linefeed is indeed always the last thing on the "line."

However, I find it simpler to strip those linefeeds anyway, and work with yours strings; then add a newline when you need it, presumably to print.

---

Since the line is in `$_` in the OP the above is really

```
s/.{12}\K.*//;
```

or, if we wanted to also assign the (truncated) line to a lexical at this opportunity

```
my $line = s/.{12}\K.*//r;
```

where the `/r` modifier makes it return the changed string. Thanks to ysth and ikegami for comments.

---

This post originally made a statement that "*Starting the regex engine is  likely more expensive than `substr` + append*", and here is an update (reversal) to that.

My benchmark shows the regex being clearly faster, when comparing

```
$_ = substr($_, 0, 12) . "\n";
```

with

```
s/.{12}\K.*//;
```

The exact benchmark result varies on details, as this is such a quick operation that overhead affects the benchmark. But I find regex faster always (well) upwards of 50%.

Comment: or `s/^.{12}\K.*//`

Comment: @ysth Sure, added, thank you  (don't need the anchor though .. ?)

Comment: could make a difference if there are characters after a newline

Comment: @ysth Ah, that; I assumed that we have "normal" lines. added a comment

Comment: @ikegami Right, I forgot that they gave us that information. Updated, thank you

Answer (score 0):

`$Line=substr($_,0,12)` with this  code truncation will happen if $_ length is greater than 12. If the `$_` value came from a line read, it usually has a newline `\n` at then end. When truncation happens this of course will be removed. What you can do is to manually add it with:

```
if (length $_ > 12) {$Line .= "\n";}
```

or you can do `chomp` before truncating the string

```
chomp;
$Line  = substr($_,0,12);
$Line .= "\n";
```

Comment: How come it will never be true? The poster said the string is being truncated that means the original string in $_ can sometimes be greater than 12. So after being truncated in his code

`$Line=substr($_,0,12);`

It checks the length of the original string if it is greater than 12 then I put back/concatenate new line.

Comment: I was mistaken.